# I want the ability to easily silence all text messages

Tags: iphone, messages, notifications, text

TL;DR: Is there a way to toggle all message notifications easily?

While at work, I want the ability to by notified by phone calls, and reminders and event notifications, but I don't want to be interrupted by text messages. As soon as I get off work, I want to be notified by incoming text messages.

Answer (score 1):

Settings → Notifications → Messages and turn off Allow Notifications.

[iOS 12 Shortcuts](https://www.apple.com/ios/ios-12-preview/) should let you create a shortcut for this so you don't have to navigate manually.

Comment: I or @grg can edit this answer once iOS 12 Shortcuts becomes available